# Video is not clear after using FFMPEG4ANDROID compress video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am building an app where i need to compress video before uploading it to server. the video without compressing is about Five minutes,60M,Android video bit 2x1024x1024,640*480. Now I am using FFMPEG library to compress video http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html .The following is command **commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i " + url + " -strict experimental -vf crop=480:480:0:0 -s 480x480 -r 30 -aspect 1:1 -ab 44100 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 300k " + demoVideoFolder + "out.mp4";**. successful but not clear at all. here is my question : is there only way to compress video by reducing bitrate? I hope to get video after compressing is as same as the original video. is anyone give me some advice ? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i " + url + " -strict experimental -vf crop=480:480:0:0 -r 30 -aspect 1:1 -ab 44100 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -vcodec libx264" + demoVideoFolder + "out.mp4";
```

Since you're cropping to 480x4480, there's no point to the size option set afterwards. I've switched codecs to the more effficient x264, which by default will use CRF 23 and provide a decent quality. If you don't have x264 linked in your FFmpeg, revert to mpeg4 with a bitrate of around 700k.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command i have worked

ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -strict experimental -vf transpose=1 -s 160x120 -r 30 -aspect 3:2 -ab 32000 -ac 2 -ar 12000 -b 150k /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4

Comment: -b 150K ? is the video you compressed clear ?  the video I compressed with 300K isn't clear enough and with mosaic。

Comment: i am not exact sure but my video is compress 80MB to 5 to 6MB